# persistenc​e gtk.view with shelve module

Tags: python-module

I have some difficult to manage persistence of gtk.view object with shelve module.

I use python 2.6.5 and PyGtk.

MY FIRST TEST
I implemented process with basic object like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

## -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

'''test de shelve
'''
import gtk
import gobject
import shelve
import os
class ShelveDemo(object):
    def **init**(self):
        self.variable1 ='essai'
        self.variable2 ='1'
        self.variable3 ='15'
        self.variable4 =15000

```
def affiche(self):
    print self.variable1
    print self.variable2
    print self.variable3
    print self.variable4
def save(self,objet):
    save_file = os.path.abspath( "D:\sphinx" + os.sep + 'essai2.tvw')
    db = shelve.open(save_file)
    db['cle1']=objet
    print
    print "liste des clé enregistrée",db.keys
    print
    db.close()
    print('sauvegarde ok')

def load(self):
    save_file = os.path.abspath("D:\sphinx" + os.sep + 'essai2.tvw')

    xx = shelve.open(save_file)
    print
    print "liste des clé loading....",xx.keys
    print
    objet1 = xx['cle1']
    objet1.affiche()
    xx.close()
```

test = ShelveDemo()
test.affiche()
test.save(test)
test.load()

It's run ok . fine !!!!!!!

TEST 2 with textView

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

## -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

'''Text Widget/Hypertext
Usually, tags modify the appearance of text in the view, e.g. making it
bold or colored or underlined. But tags are not restricted to appearance.
They can also affect the behavior of mouse and key presses, as this demo
shows.'''

## pygtk version: Maik Hertha

import gtk
import pango
import gobject
import shelve_whc as shelve
import os
from printv import printv
class test_affiche:
    def **init**(self,bufferr):
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.connect('destroy', lambda *w: gtk.main_quit())
        self.window.set_title(self.**class**._*name*_+' clone')
        self.window.set_default_size(450, 450)
        self.window.set_border_width(0)

```
    view = gtk.TextView()
    view.set_buffer(bufferr)
    view.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_WORD) #c'est utile car il y a en permanence une partie cachée pas top pour une aide
    sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
    self.window.add(sw)
    sw.add(view)
    self.window.show_all()
```

class HypertextDemo(gtk.Window):
    hovering_over_link = False
    hand_cursor = gtk.gdk.Cursor(gtk.gdk.HAND2)
    regular_cursor = gtk.gdk.Cursor(gtk.gdk.XTERM)
    def save(self,bufferr):
        save_file = os.path.abspath("D:\sphinx" + os.sep + 'essai.tvw')
        db = shelve.open(save_file,protocol=2) # protocol=2 est nécessaire pour traiter objet complexe type TextBuffer
        printv (buffer)
        print type(buffer)
        db['cle']=bufferr
        db.close()
        print('sauvegarde ok')
        # fonction de test pour savoir ce que je sauvegarde
        essai = test_affiche(bufferr)
        printv( bufferr)

```
def load(self):
    save_file = os.path.abspath("D:\sphinx" + os.sep + 'essai.tvw')
    db = shelve.open(save_file,protocol=2) # protocol=2 est nécessaire pour traiter objet complexe type TextBuffer
    print
    print "liste des clé enregistrée",db.keys()
    print
    conteneur = db['cle']
    print "type de l'objet en cours de chargement %s" %type(conteneur)
    print "nom  de l'objet en cours de chargement %s" %conteneur.__class__.__name__
    printv (conteneur)
    # fonction de test pour savoir ce que je sauvegarde
    essai3 = test_affiche(conteneur)
    db.close()

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    gtk.Window.__init__(self)
    try:
        self.set_screen(parent.get_screen())
    except AttributeError:
        self.connect('destroy', lambda *w: gtk.main_quit())
    self.set_title(self.__class__.__name__)
    self.set_default_size(450, 450)
    self.set_border_width(0)
    view = gtk.TextView()
    view.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_WORD) #c'est utile car il y a en permanence une partie cachée pas top pour une aide
    view.connect("key-press-event", self.key_press_event)
    view.connect("event-after", self.event_after)
    view.connect("motion-notify-event", self.motion_notify_event)
    view.connect("visibility-notify-event", self.visibility_notify_event)
    buffer = view.get_buffer()
    sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
    self.add(sw)
    sw.add(view)
    self.show_page(buffer, 1)
    self.show_all()
    self.save(view.get_buffer())
    self.load()
# Links can be activated by pressing Enter.
def key_press_event(self, text_view, event):
    if (event.keyval == gtk.gdk.Return or
        event.keyval == gtk.gdk.KP_Enter):
        buffer = text_view.get_buffer()
        iter = buffer.get_iter_at_mark(buffer.get_insert())
        self.follow_if_link(text_view, iter)
    return False
# Links can also be activated by clicking.
def event_after(self, text_view, event):
    if event.type != gtk.gdk.BUTTON_RELEASE:
        return False
    if event.button != 1:
        return False
    buffer = text_view.get_buffer()
    # we shouldn't follow a link if the user has selected something
    try:
        start, end = buffer.get_selection_bounds()
    except ValueError:
        # If there is nothing selected, None is return
        pass
    else:
        if start.get_offset() != end.get_offset():
            return False
    x, y = text_view.window_to_buffer_coords(gtk.TEXT_WINDOW_WIDGET,
        int(event.x), int(event.y))
    iter = text_view.get_iter_at_location(x, y)
    self.follow_if_link(text_view, iter)
    return False

# Looks at all tags covering the position (x, y) in the text view,
# and if one of them is a link, change the cursor to the "hands" cursor
# typically used by web browsers.
def set_cursor_if_appropriate(self, text_view, x, y):
    hovering = False
    buffer = text_view.get_buffer()
    iter = text_view.get_iter_at_location(x, y)
    tags = iter.get_tags()
    for tag in tags:
        page = tag.get_data("page")
        if page != 0:
            hovering = True
            break
    if hovering != self.hovering_over_link:
        self.hovering_over_link = hovering
    if self.hovering_over_link:
        text_view.get_window(gtk.TEXT_WINDOW_TEXT).set_cursor(self.hand_cursor)
    else:
        text_view.get_window(gtk.TEXT_WINDOW_TEXT).set_cursor(self.regular_cursor)
# Update the cursor image if the pointer moved.
def motion_notify_event(self, text_view, event):
    x, y = text_view.window_to_buffer_coords(gtk.TEXT_WINDOW_WIDGET,
        int(event.x), int(event.y))
    self.set_cursor_if_appropriate(text_view, x, y)
    text_view.window.get_pointer()
    return False
# Also update the cursor image if the window becomes visible
# (e.g. when a window covering it got iconified).
def visibility_notify_event(self, text_view, event):
    wx, wy, mod = text_view.window.get_pointer()
    bx, by = text_view.window_to_buffer_coords(gtk.TEXT_WINDOW_WIDGET, wx, wy)
    self.set_cursor_if_appropriate (text_view, bx, by)
    return False
def insert_link(self, buffer, iter, text, page):
    ''' Inserts a piece of text into the buffer, giving it the usual
        appearance of a hyperlink in a web browser: blue and underlined.
        Additionally, attaches some data on the tag, to make it recognizable
        as a link.
    '''
    tag = buffer.create_tag(None,
        foreground="blue", underline=pango.UNDERLINE_SINGLE)
    tag.set_data("page", page)
    buffer.insert_with_tags(iter, text, tag)

def show_page(self, buffer, page):
    ''' Fills the buffer with text and interspersed links. In any real
        hypertext app, this method would parse a file to identify the links.
    '''
    buffer.set_text("", 0)
    iter = buffer.get_iter_at_offset(0)
    if page == 1:
        buffer.insert(iter, "Some text to show that simple ")
        self.insert_link(buffer, iter, "hypertext", 3)
        buffer.insert(iter, " can easily be realized with ")
        self.insert_link(buffer, iter, "tags", 2)
        buffer.insert(iter, ".")
        buffer.insert(iter, "\n")
        buffer.insert(iter, 'Inserts a piece of text into the buffer, giving it the usual'
        'appearance of a hyperlink in a web browser: blue and underlined.'
        'Additionally, attaches some data on the tag, to make it recognizable'
        'as a link')
        buffer.insert(iter, "\n")
        buffer.insert(iter, 'Inserts a piece of text into the buffer, giving it the usual'
        'appearance of a hyperlink in a web browser: blue and underlined.'
        'Additionally, attaches some data on the tag, to make it recognizable'
        'as a link')
    elif page == 2:
        buffer.insert(iter,
            "A tag is an attribute that can be applied to some range of text. "
            "For example, a tag might be called \"bold\" and make the text inside "
            "the tag bold. However, the tag concept is more general than that "
            "tags don't have to affect appearance. They can instead affect the "
            "behavior of mouse and key presses, \"lock\" a range of text so the "
            "user can't edit it, or countless other things.\n", -1)
        self.insert_link(buffer, iter, "Go back", 1)
    elif page == 3:
        tag = buffer.create_tag(None, weight=pango.WEIGHT_BOLD)
        buffer.insert_with_tags(iter, "hypertext:\n", tag)
        buffer.insert(iter,
            "machine-readable text that is not sequential but is organized "
            "so that related items of information are connected.\n")
        self.insert_link(buffer, iter, "Go back", 1)

def follow_if_link(self, text_view, iter):
    ''' Looks at all tags covering the position of iter in the text view,
        and if one of them is a link, follow it by showing the page identified
        by the data attached to it.
    '''
    tags = iter.get_tags()
    for tag in tags:
        page = tag.get_data("page")
        if page != 0:
            self.show_page(text_view.get_buffer(), page)
            break
```

def main():

```
HypertextDemo()
gtk.main()
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
main()
```

Concerning test 2, reload action is not ok like if persistence action do not occur

Can I have some explanation were is my mistake
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry It's a small mistake for other people

replace  import shelve_whc as shelve

by import shelve